# Retrofitting a Spring app to use Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

We want to add Tomcat as an embedded web server to our existing Spring application.

Our app is not built using Spring Boot, but we would like to look at using Boot configuration for adding Tomcat, as it's likely going to make the process a lot simpler.

Is this possible to use Spring Boot for this, given the fact that we not currently using Boot?

In any case, how difficult or feasible is it to retrofit or re-architect an existing application to use Spring Boot?

Thanks

Comment: That is pretty doable, but might depend on the version of Spring you are using and which version of Spring Boot you are trying to use.

Comment: Using Spring 4.1.0, presumably we would want the latest and greatest Boot version

Comment: I would start upgrading Spring to the latest before going to Spring Boot. The same would apply to other dependencies you use, upgrade them one by one instead of all at once. Generally this is a drop in replacement but you don't want to run into weird issues due to upgrading everything at once. Once that is done, use the Spring Boot starters to manage your dependencies. If that works, rewrite your bootstrapping to the Spring Boot way (I,e a main class and/or a `SpringBootServletInitializer`) and load your old configuration files (use `@Import` and `@ImportResouce`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introducing Spring Boot in an existing Spring application is very well doable but might depend on your Spring version.

A successful approach that I've applied a couple of times is.

1. Upgrade your dependencies to the Spring Boot supported ones
2. Let the Spring Boot Starter project manage your dependencies
3. Create a Spring Boot launch class
4. Strip your configuration to use the Spring Boot auto configuration

### Upgrade Dependencies

If you have different dependencies then Spring Boot you suddenly might have newer, incompatible, dependencies when upgrading directly to Spring Boot. What I tend to do, is upgrade the dependencies 1 at a time and make sure the application still works. (See this [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml) for the versions).

You could upgrade everything at once, but you might get issues and then it is hard to figure out what lead to the issue.

### Let Spring Boot Manage Dependencies

After upgrading the dependencies you probably want to cleanup the dependencies and use the `spring-boot-starter-*` projects to have your dependencies managed. That way they follow the Spring Boot versioning scheme and you are certain you have the right versions.

You probably also want to use the [Spring Boot parent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-parent-pom) as a parent project when using a `pom.xml`.

### Use Spring Boot to bootstrap the application

Now you probably want to use Spring Boot to bootstrap your application and re-use your existing configuration classes and/or XML configuration files. The existing configuration classes can quite easily be detected and you can use `@ImportResource` to include existing XML configuration files.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("<your-existing-xml-config>")
public class YourApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplicationRun(YourApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

*Pro-Tip:* Put this class in your most top level available package, something like `com.company.your-app`, this way later on Spring Boot can detect your services, controllers etc. instead of you having to manually configure the component scanning etc.

This should give you a running and functional application which would still use your own configuration.

### Use Spring Boot Auto Configuration

The final step would be to strip down your own configuration and use the Spring Boot auto configuration where applicable. Again do this in small iterations/steps. I tend to do it bean by bean (first the `DataSource`, then the `EntityManagerFactory` etc. etc.) that way you incrementally start using more and more of the features of Spring Boot.